# adding Import-Module command in Powershell script called from C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I have few unit cases written which is calling the PowerShell cmdlet which is being created in another project under same solution. so structure is like this

```
Solution
 -- Project A(Powershell modules)
 ---Project B (Unit test cases)
 ------testcases.cs
 ------powershellscript.ps1
```

Now in testcases.cs file I have a unit test case written(see below) which calls powershellscript.ps1 and in powershellscript.ps1 I have few lines of command and first is `Import-Module "C:\Users\..\source\repos\....\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\ProjectA.dll"`

As you see I am writing Import with full path of dll for Project A . How can I fix this as it will require me to have a common path for projectA.dll? below is my unit test code which calls this script file:

```
[Fact]
        public void VerifyGetDocument()
        {
            string path = Path.Combine( Root, "powershellScript.ps1" );
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            runspace.Open();
            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript( path );
            Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
            runspace.Close();

}
```

Comment: Put the dll in a system PATH, add the current path to PATHS or create a PATH variable for it and use that?

Comment: you meant PATH from environment variable

Comment: Either put it in the system path or create your own environment variable path yes.

Comment: What if my PowerShell project is referenced in Project B. then also do i need to put a Path variable??